# How do you assess the impact of an attached event function on performance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, performance-testing

I am building out a UI Framework as an application template. It's built on jQuery / Bootstrap. It will be used by web app developers to build data driven apps for the company I work for.

There are countless screen scenarios to consider. for example, I am adding a scroll event that calls a function to fix the header if the page scrolls horizontally.

**My question is:**
If I add scroll, resize or mouse move event functions to the global frame work, how can I test their impact on performance. I don't want to laden the framework down little by little.

Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 0):

you can use developers tools profiler, but you can be sure that calling stuff on every event gonna impact on site performance.

if you do hook to all this event i would suggest do it wise and use ["throttle"](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle).
and try to build some light weight logic that will prevent unexpected/necessary class.

and test your code it also can tell how much time it take to run each test which can indicate on your logic performance.